# No traffic goes through when I connect to VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

I am trying to configure my OpenWrt router to allow me to share my VPN connection between several devices.

When my router is not connected to VPN, the computer has internet access. When the router connects to VPN (I can verify that by running traceroute on router), the computer doesn't have internet access.

I think it has something to do with routing, but I have no idea where to start.

First I installed package `ppp-mod-pptp`

Then I added interface `vpn` as:

```
config interface 'vpn'
        option 'ifname' 'pptp-vpn'
        option proto 'pptp'
        option server 'XXX'
        option username 'YYY'
        option password 'ZZZ'
        option buffering '1'
```

then vpn connects, I can verify that `vpn` interface shows up in `ifconfig -a`, and I can see in traceroute that traffic does indeed go through the VPN. But I cannot connect anywhere from the computer, yet.

Then the tutorial tells me to add VPN interface to WAN firewall zone (I don't know what is the effect of this, maybe that is the culprit).

Then I install package `ip`, and changed file `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` to add a new table named 'vpn'

```
# reserved values
#
255  local
254  main
253  default
10   vpn
0    unspec
```

Then I added ip rules

```
ip rule add from<pc_ip> table vpn
ip route add default via <tunnel_ip> dev pptp-vpn table vpn
```

where `<pc_ip>` is the IP address of my computer and `<tunnel_ip>` the current IP address I was assigned by the VPN connection.

Now the tutorial says that the connection on my computer should work, but I cannot ping anything, open anything from browser, nothing.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

So, what was missing was setting up Traffic control in the Firewall options, as quoted from OpenWrt wiki:

> Go to Network / Firewall / Traffic Control and use "Add entry' to put
>   a 'Source' lan - 'Destination' vpn (the name you gave to it) to allow
>   traffic form your LAN to go to the VPN. Then verify your Network /
>   Firewall settings. Your VPN will be now in the 'Zones' area, but with
>   everything set as 'reject'. Just change 'OUTPUT' to accept and check
>   the 'MASQ' box to enable NAT for the traffic going through the VPN.